# Unable to identify greeting link after logging into the flipkart application

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Actions expected out of the code below :

- User successfully logs in.
- User moves to the top right corner of the website and clicks on the greeting link "Hi ....!".

Step 2 is not happening because the greeting hyperlink is not identified by WebDriver. What am I doing wrong?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://flipkart.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/div/header/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[8]/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='fk-input login-form-input user-email']")).sendKeys("emailid");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='fk-input login-form-input user-pwd']")).sendKeys("password");      
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-mainbody-id']/div/div/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[7]/input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Greeting _link")).click();
```

Error message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Greeting _link"}

The HTML is:

```
<li class="_2sYLhZ _2mEF1S" data-reactid="26"> 
    <a class="_1AHrFc _2k0gmP" data-reactid="27" href="#">Hi Neha!</a> 
    <ul class="_1u5ANM" data-reactid="28">
```

Comment: where is your HTML?

Comment: Your problem could be caused by having no "wait" mechanism. try implementing wait to allow page to fully load before clicking on anything

Comment: I can't see any link with text `Greeting _link` after login into flipkart website.. cloud you tell us where is this link???

Comment: the greeting _ link is nothing but the link where you hover your mouse to get the log out option- eg in my case it shows - Hi Neha!

Comment: the HTML is <li class="_2sYLhZ _2mEF1S" data-reactid="26">
<a class="_1AHrFc _2k0gmP" data-reactid="27" href="#">Hi Neha!</a>
<ul class="_1u5ANM" data-reactid="28">

Comment: @NehaMishra, I just added your HTML to your question, is that correct?

Comment: @YuZhang- Yes Thanks!!  but somehow I am not able to make selenium identify that element ...

Comment: Tried this one ----------------------------------------------------------------Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                 WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='container']/div/div/header/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[7]/a"));
                    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
                    act.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    driver.quit();

Comment: -----another code 2-------------------------------------------------------------------Actions action = new Actions(driver);
 WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@data-reactid='27']"));
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();

    driver.quit();
I added thread.sleep () command too but in vain

Answer (score 0):

As I seeing after login there is no link which looks like as `Hi username..!`, but accroding to your comment I observe that you are talking about `My account` link which is visible in my case, I'm just rewriting your code which will automate from login to logout as below :-

```
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Log In"))).click(); //it will click on login button

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.user-email"))).sendKeys("user name"); //it will fill user name

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.user-pwd"))).sendKeys('password'); //it will fill password

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.login-btn"))).click(); //it will click on login button

WebElement myAccount = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("My Account")));
Mouse mouse = ((HasInputDevices)driver).getMouse();
mouse.mouseMove(((Locatable)hoverElement).getCoordinates()); //it will perform mouse over on My Account link, if in your case it show as 'Hi Neha!' you can replace it.

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Log Out"))).click(); //it will click on logout click after mouse over
```

Hope it helps..:)